# sed to replace random numbers

Tags: random, sed, numbers, replace, sh

I need to let sed replace some url in a lot of files. Each file has the following

```
 http://www.expample.com/file.php?id=xxxxxxx
```

where `xxxxx` consist of random numbers, random depth in each file like

```
file 1

_h**p://www.expample.com/file.php?id=xx

file 2

_h**p://www.expample.com/file.php?id=xxxxxxxx
```

etc. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you want to replace them with?

Comment: What are you trying to replace, and what do you want to the replacement text to be?

Comment: You should really consider writing your questions more carefully. I can hardly understand what you're saying.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments say you will need to tell us what you want to replace them with.

But in the mean time something to chew on

```
sed s/id\=[0-9]+/id\=/     file*.*
```

if they are hex digits

```
sed s/id\=[0-9A-Fa-f]+/id\=/     file*.*
```

Comment: thanks for your hard work, i need to replace it with blank like
<br/>
sed -i 's%expample.com/file.php?id=xxxxxxx%g' file.php the problem is 
<br/>
the random and auto generated numbers xxxxxxx

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -e "s/(http:\/\/www\.example\.com\/file\.php\?id=\d+)([^\d]|$)/YOUR_REPLACEMENT\2"
```

should do it... Untested though, I'm sitting at a sed-less Windows box right now.

Comment: boo for sitting at a windows box! And no cygwin!